# Hibernate Sequence get stuck at value 41

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have the following sequence in my class -

```
@Entity
public class CustomerOrder {

   @Id
   @SequenceGenerator( name = "CUSTOMER_ORDER_INVOICE_NO_SEQ_NAME", sequenceName = "CUSTOMER_ORDER_INVOICE_NO_SEQ", allocationSize = 20 )
   @GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "CUSTOMER_ORDER_INVOICE_NO_SEQ_NAME" )
   private int id;

   private long orderInvoiceNo;

   //.. getters and setters

}
```

This is spring data jpa repository class having method to get next_val

```
  @Repository
  public interface CustomerOrderRepository
    extends CrudRepository<CustomerOrder, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<CustomerOrder> {

     @Query( value = "SELECT next_val FROM CUSTOMER_ORDER_INVOICE_NO_SEQ", nativeQuery = true )
     Long getNextOrderInvoiceNoSeq();
 }
```

I need to get the next_val from the sequence and pass that value to two different places. So I am calling the getNextOrderInvoiceNoSeq() method of my repository and storing the value as orderInvoiceNo -

```
@Autowired
private CustomerOrderRepository customerOrderRepository;

public void placeCustomerOrder( CustomerOrder customerOrder )
{

 long orderInvoiceNo = customerOrderRepository.getNextOrderInvoiceNoSeq();
 customerOrder.setOrderInvoiceNo(orderInvoiceNo);

 // using the same orderInvoiceNo to my other pojo
 // CustomerPurchase customerPurchase = new CustomerPurchase
 // customerPurchase.setOrderInvoiceNo(orderInvoiceNo);

 //....
 customerOrderRepository.save(customerOrder);
}


 @Entity
 public class CustomerPurchase {

   private String itemId;
   private long orderInvoiceNo;
   //.....     
 }
```

So what is happening now for first two iteration of placing customerOrder, I am getting orderInvoiceNo as 1 and 41, but after that each time I am getting 41 as next_val from the sequence, hence making each order having same invoice no which is 41.

Comment: Which database are you using? Can you add the DDL definition for the sequence to the question? What happens if you run `SELECT next_val FROM CUSTOMER_ORDER_INVOICE_NO_SEQ` directly on the database? Do you still get 41? Or is this value just being cached by Hibernate?

Comment: I am using mysql 5.7 and the sequence table is automatically gets created. Yes i get always 41 if run the query directly on the database.

Answer (score 2):

MySQL does not have sequences so in this case Hibernate will create a table generator.

Hibernate will do a `SELECT FOR UPDATE` to get the latest `next_val` and an `UPDATE` to increment the value:

```
SELECT next_val as id_val 
FROM CUSTOMER_ORDER_INVOICE_NO_SEQ FOR UPDATE

UPDATE CUSTOMER_ORDER_INVOICE_NO_SEQ 
SET next_val= 2 where next_val=1
```

The `getNextOrderInvoiceNoSeq()` only does a `SELECT` for the latest value but does not increment it.

That said, I wouldn't recommend implementing that. It would be better to [switch to a native sequence](https://vladmihalcea.com/why-should-not-use-the-auto-jpa-generationtype-with-mysql-and-hibernate/) and have a [foreign key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15426736/how-can-i-create-a-foreign-key-constraint-using-hibernate-annotations) CustomerOrder and CustomerPurchase.

Comment: I will try this.