# I have a composite foreign key in my table, how do i define the mapping in hibernate?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, entity-framework, hibernate-mapping

I have two tables as follows:

table1:
col1, col2, col3, col4

table2:
c1, c2, c3, c4

in table 1, col1 and col2 are primary keys (composite key).
in table 2, c1 and c2 are foreign keys referencing the foreign key in table1.

how should I define this mapping in my hibernate pojos ?

Comment: I believe this question was answeared here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15426736/how-can-i-mark-a-foreign-key-constraint-using-hibernate-annotations

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I mark a foreign key constraint using Hibernate annotations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15426736/how-can-i-mark-a-foreign-key-constraint-using-hibernate-annotations)